# Titlesec: chapter in top margin

Tags: sectioning, margins, titlesec

How can I put a chapter or section title into the margin such that it is on the top of the page?

This is what I want:

[image]

But the following MWE produces

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,titletoc,marginnote}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{geometry}
% page layout
\geometry{%
    showframe,
    top=4cm,
    headsep=1.5cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    innermargin=3.0cm,
    textwidth=300pt,
    marginparwidth=4.0cm,
    marginparsep=1.5cm,
    heightrounded,
}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[rightmargin]{\Large}{Chapter~\thechapter}{10pt}{#1}


\begin{document}


\chapter{Background}

\lipsum[1]

% the following is needed or the chapter will not be displayed at all
\section{Related Work} 
\lipsum[99]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A marginnote is meant to be placed basically at the same line where `\marginnote` appears, but in the margin off-course. It's not shifted automatically!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution, based on the `display` style:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,titletoc,marginnote, array}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
% page layout
\geometry{%
    showframe,
    top=4cm,
    headsep=1.5cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    innermargin=3.0cm,
    textwidth=300pt,
    marginparwidth=4.0cm,
    marginparsep=1.5cm,
    heightrounded,
}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\LARGE\filleft\sffamily\bfseries\color{SlateGray3}}{}{0pt}{\leavevmode%
\rlap{\hskip\marginparsep\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} >{\centering}p{\marginparwidth}@{}}Chapter~\thechapter\\#1\end{tabular}}}}[\vskip-2.63ex]%
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-9ex}{0pt}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Background}

\lipsum[1]

% the following is needed or the chapter will not be displayed at all
\section{Related Work}
\lipsum[99-102]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rightmargin` placement, but you need to make `\chapter` a member of the `straight` class.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,marginnote}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
% page layout
\geometry{%
    showframe,
    top=4cm,
    headsep=1.5cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    innermargin=3.0cm,
    textwidth=300pt,
    marginparwidth=4.0cm,
    marginparsep=1.5cm,
    heightrounded,
}%

\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}[rightmargin]
  {\Large}
  {\makebox[0pt][l]{Chapter~\thechapter}}
  {10pt}
  {\marginchapter}
\preto\chapter{\cleardoublepage}
\newcommand{\marginchapter}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{%
      \raggedright#1%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Background}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Related Work} 
\lipsum[99]

\end{document}
```

[image]